# A Python class calculating the mean value of numbers being passed one by one to the class

Tags: python, class, mean

I defined class Average as follows and it gives me the average of numbers.

```
class Average:
    #lisst=[]
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value=value
        #Average.lisst.append(self)
    def add(self, other,k):
        return Average(self.value +(other.value-self.value)/float(k))
```

This is the question without any changes:
First: Write a Python class calculating the mean value of numbers being passed one by one to the class. It should have a put(x) method that feeds it a number and a get() method returning the mean value of the numbers passed so far.
Second: Write a framework class that has an append(o) method that takes an object like the ones above (i.e. ones that have a put method to process data and a get method to retrieve a result). It should itself have a put(x) method, which will pass the x on to all the objects o passed to it via append and a get method which will return a list containing the results of the get calls of all the contained 
objects.
I don't actually understand what is want. I just need a hint to continue. Thanks.

PS This is not a mandatory class assignment and I do not get any point for it. Just to clarify that I am NOT cheating.

Comment: `I don't actually understand what is want.` Me too ^_^

Comment: You assignment asked you to create a *class* to calculate the average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you should direct this question to the Powers That Be of your course: the instructor, teaching assistant, etc.

Second, do you have the original assignment wording?  What you've written is inconsistent or incomplete in several respects.

However, to get you going in the meantime ...

> an object like the ones above (i.e. ones that have a put method to
>   process data and a get method to retrieve a result)

Your `Average` class has neither at the moment; you have to add them.  It appears that `add` might be the processing method.

> It should itself have a put(x) method, which will pass the x on to all
>   the objects o passed to it via append

I'm confused here.  `append` can construct a list, but it does not pass on objects.  Were *I* designing the system, I'd take this as a hint that my user program should collect the `Average` objects in a list, and pass that list to the framework's `put` method.

> a get method which will return a list containing the results of the
>   get calls of all the contained objects.

The framework needs to maintain a list of objects for which it is responsible.  `framework.get` simply iterates through the `Average.get` for each object, returning a list of results.

In code terms, I'm seeing something like this:

```
class Average:
    # stuff to add
    def put(self, new_value):
       ...
    def get(self):
        return self.value

class Avg_FW:
    def __init__(self, avg_list):
        # maintain the list of all Average objects
    def put(self, new_value):
        # Invoke Average.put on each average in your list
    def get(self):
        # Invoke Average.get on each average in your list
        # Return a list of the results
```

Does that clarify the structure enough to continue?
Does it match what you know about the course?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with a list variable (which you have already done).

You can use the default constructor.

The add/append/put function appends the input number to the list. You could also check to verify that the input is a number (int or float/double).

The average function returns the average of the numbers in the list.

The actual implementation is left to the reader as an exercise.